# If $Y$ is a normal random variable and $E[Y\mid X]$ is also a normal random variable, does it mean that $X$ is a normal random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. If $Y$ is a (non-degenerate) normal random variable and $E[Y\mid X]$ is also a (non-degenerate) normal random variable, does it mean that $X$ is necessarily a normal random variable ? How would one show that ?

Comment: By non-degenerate you mean non-constant?

Comment: Exactly, variance strictly bigger than 0

Comment: In general no, if $f$ is any injective function, then $\mathbb{E}[Y|f(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[Y|Y] = Y$ which is normally distributed, but $X = f(Y)$ is not.

Comment: Thank you! What if we impose that $X\neq f(Y)$ so that $\sigma(X) \neq \sigma (Y)$ ?

Comment: W. Volante  and @rubikscube09 wait why do we need to assume non-degenerate? if $A$ is normal, then $A$ is non-degenerate a fortiori...right? aaahhhhhh or what is meant is like $A \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2=0^2)$? [What a troll](https://youtu.be/OwnR-sewxpk?t=2071) a person is to consider that constants or a.s. constants as normal random variables! hahaha Edit: That troll would have to tell wiki to adjust its pdf for normal rv's as the one it has for positive $\sigma$ and then the degenerate one for zero $\sigma$ because FML if we're gonna do $\frac{1}{0\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: @W.Volante: It is possible to find a Borel function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is injective.  So take $X = f(Y,Z)$ where $Z$ is nontrivial and independent of $Y$.  Then $\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y,Z) \supsetneq \sigma(Y)$ and we again have $E[Y \mid X] = Y$.  If by some miracle $X$ happens to be normally distributed then replace $f$ by $e^f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Y \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$.

$\mathbb E[Y \mid e^Y] = \mathbb E[Y\mid Y] = Y \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, but $e^Y \not\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: very nice, thank you. What if we impose that $X\neq f(Y)$ so that $\sigma(X) \neq \sigma (Y)$

Comment: @W.Volante right so we've finally found the better question to ask. create new post?

Comment: @W.Volante but i think what you mean is $X \ne f(Y)$ s.t. $\sigma(X) \subsetneq \sigma(Y)$ (or at least not necessarily $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$) because i believe $X = f(Y)$ means $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$ but not necessarily $\supseteq$